# Parametrization between $f$ and $-f$ preserving its $L^2$ norm

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parametrization, geodesic

I am interested in the ''canonical'' parametrization $f_\lambda\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\cap C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$ between $f_0=f$ and $f_1=-f$ where $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\cap C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$, with $\|f_\lambda\|_{L^2}=\|f\|_{L^2}$. $C^\infty$ assumption is just to prevent any problem regarding regularity, and to discard almost trivial (but not so much useful) candidate $f_\lambda:=(\chi_{A(\lambda)}-\chi_{A(\lambda)^c})f$ with $A(\lambda)=[-\tan(\pi\lambda/2),\tan(\pi\lambda/2)]^c$.

This makes me think of finding a geodesic on a sphere, but now the sphere is infinite dimensional (is it Hilbert manifold?), and I don't know much about it. So the questions are:

1. Is there any parametrization $f_\lambda$ as described above (I guess yes)?
2. If so, is it possible to explicitely express $f_\lambda$?
3. Inspired in case of Euclidean ball, can we find the parametrization $f_{\lambda,\xi}$ for any $\xi\in L^2\cap C^\infty$ such that $\langle f,\xi\rangle=0$, with $\frac{d}{d\lambda}f_{\lambda,\xi}|_{\lambda=0}=\xi$?

For the context of the question, I am interested in the minimization problem of nonlocal Hartree type energy functional
$$F(f):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f(-\Delta+m^2)^sf-f^2(-\Delta)^{-1}f^2,\quad m\geq 0.$$
I wonder if such a parametrization can be constructed, and if it is possible to show that $\frac{d}{d\lambda}F(f_\lambda)=0$ only has a single solution on $\lambda\in(0,1)$ (this derivative should be zero at $\lambda=0,1$) with $\frac{d^2}{d\lambda^2}F(f_\lambda)<0$ at the given extrema, then this seems to help the understanding of the uniqueness property tremendously. But of course this cannot be processed as easy as this, because probably the solution to Euler-Lagrange of $F$ is not unique unless we give a further structure (e.g. assuming ground state solution).

Comment: Is multiplying by $e^{i \lambda \pi}$ also too trivial?

Comment: @CameronWilliams That is a very nice example! So it deals with the question 1 and 2, in case of complex valued space. However for now I am interested in real valued functions, and especially the problem 3 is the most interesting part. Thank you for the insight :)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific for (3)? If $\langle f, \xi\rangle = 0$ for any $\xi$, then $f \equiv 0$. Is $\xi$ fixed? Is $\lambda$ independent of $\xi$? I came up with a way to do (1) and (2) without complex numbers but realized that you also wanted (3) satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a function $\xi\in L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ that is orthogonal to $f$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ and such that $\| \xi \|_{L^2(\Omega)}=1$. Now define $$ f_{\lambda,\xi} = \cos(\pi \lambda) f+\sin(\pi \lambda ) \xi. $$ Then $f_{0,\xi}=f$, $f_{1,\xi}=-f$, \begin{align*}
\| f_{\lambda,\xi}\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}^2&= \cos^2(\pi \lambda) \| f\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}^2+\sin^2(\pi \lambda ) \|\xi\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}^2 + 2 \sin(\pi \lambda )\cos(\pi \lambda) (f,\xi)_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

Moreover, $$\frac{d}{d\lambda}\bigg \vert_{\lambda=0}f_{\lambda,\xi}=\pi 
\xi. $$

Comment: Oof dang I had a much more convoluted idea along the same lines. I broke the Hilbert space into a bunch of 2D subspaces and used rotation matrices. This is way more elegant. Great answer!

Comment: Addendum: this only works as written if $\|f\|=1$. If not, just scale $\xi$ by $\|f\|$.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!